# DBpedia Query: SnorQL VS SparQL VS QueryBuilder?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

What are http://dbpedia.org/snorql/ and http://dbpedia.org/sparql/ and http://querybuilder.dbpedia.org/ ?

Both SnorQL VS SparQL seems to run the following code similarly :

```
SELECT ?resource ?value
WHERE { 
   ?resource a <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/CitiesAndTownsInDenmark> .
   ?resource <http://dbpedia.org/property/populationTotal> ?value .
   FILTER (?value > 100000)
}
ORDER BY ?resource ?value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are (different) user interfaces that let you build and execute SPARQL queries on the DBpedia SPARQL endpoint http://dbpedia.org/sparql/.

The results should be the same in all three environments, because they use the same endpoint (thus the same data).