# DBPedia's SPARQL and SNORQL returning different results

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

In the [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/), running

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?a (3+3 AS ?y)
WHERE 
{ 
   ?a dc:description "English footballer" .
   ?a dbpedia2:placeOfBirth :Merseyside .
}
```

Shows all `English Footballers` who were born in Merseyside, with column `y` just displaying the value `6` on every row [[result link](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=++++PREFIX+dc%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A++++PREFIX+dbpedia2%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A++++SELECT+%3Fa+%283%2B3+AS+%3Fy%29%0D%0A++++WHERE+%0D%0A++++%7B+%0D%0A+++++++%3Fa+dc%3Adescription+%22English+footballer%22+.%0D%0A+++++++%3Fa+dbpedia2%3AplaceOfBirth+%3AMerseyside+.%0D%0A++++%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)]; however, the [same query](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX+pos%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+%3Fa+%283%2B3+AS+%3Fy%29%0D%0AWHERE+%0D%0A%7B+%0D%0A+++++%3Fa+dc%3Adescription+%22English+footballer%22+.%0D%0A+++++%3Fa+dbpedia2%3AplaceOfBirth+%3AMerseyside+.%0D%0A%7D) on the [SNORQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/) displays an error:

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 16: syntax error at '3'
before 'AS' SPARQL query: define sql:big-data-const 0 #output-
format:application/sparql-results+json define input:default-graph-uri PREFIX 
owl: PREFIX xsd: PREFIX rdfs: PREFIX rdf: PREFIX foaf: PREFIX dc: PREFIX : 
PREFIX dbpedia2: PREFIX dbpedia: PREFIX skos: PREFIX pos: PREFIX dbo: SELECT 
?a (3 3 AS ?y) WHERE { ?a dc:description "English footballer" . ?a 
dbpedia2:placeOfBirth :Merseyside . }
```

Even more strangely, using any of the other 3 arithmetic operators *does* work in the SNORQL endpoint (e.g. [with division](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX+pos%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+%3Fa+%283%2F3+AS+%3Fy%29%0D%0AWHERE+%0D%0A%7B+%0D%0A+++++%3Fa+dc%3Adescription+%22English+footballer%22+.%0D%0A+++++%3Fa+dbpedia2%3AplaceOfBirth+%3AMerseyside+.%0D%0A%7D))

[A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15658884/889604) has implied that the SPARQL and SNORQL endpoints should return the same result, so what's going on here?!

Comment: also posted to the dbpedia-discussion mailing list: http://sourceforge.net/p/dbpedia/mailman/message/33467351/.

Comment: I only found out that dbpedia had a mailing list after I posted the question

Comment: Crossposting isn't necessarily bad, but it's polite to let people know. After all, a response has already been posted on the mailing list that the problem is in the + not getting encoded, so it turns into `(3 3 as`.  Without the link, people here could still be spending time debugging this too.

Comment: Yeah - sorry, I should have been more explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The snorql code used the 'escape' javascript function which is not the correct function to encode a piece of text that needs to be embedded as an parameter argument to the official /sparql endpoint.

This caused the + character to be transferred as literal, and decoded by the /sparql endpoint as a space character, altering the syntax of your query.

We fixed the snorql code on dbpedia.org to use the encodeURIComponent as in:

url = url + '&query=' + encodeURIComponent(query_text);

Answer (score 1):

Kingsley Idehen replied on the mailing list that:

> The snorql doesn't encode properly plus, so the expression becomes :
>   "SELECT ?a (3 3 AS ?y)” which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Closure proof, via a "[Cool URI](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX%20pos%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20%3Fa%20%283%2B3%20AS%20%3Fy%29%0D%0AWHERE%20%0D%0A%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fa%20dc%3Adescription%20%22English%20footballer%22%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fa%20dbpedia2%3AplaceOfBirth%20%3AMerseyside%20.%0D%0A%7D)" that's loosely-coupled to actual data state.